# wget files from FTP-like listings

Tags: wget

So, site that used to use FTP now has an HTTP front-end and won't allow FTP connections. The [site in question](http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD09GA.005/) (for an example directory) will show a page with links to different dates. Inside each of these different dates, there are many files, and I typically just need to get some file with some clear pattern e.g. `*h17v04*.hdf`. I thought this could work:

```
wget -I "${PLATFORM}/${PRODUCT}/${YEAR}.*" -r -l 4 \
   --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1" \
   --verbose -c -np -nc -nd  \
   -A "*h17v04*.hdf" http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/$PLATFORM/$PRODUCT/
```

where `PLATFORM=MOLT`, `PRODUCT=MOD09GA.005` and `YEAR=2004`, for example. This seems to start looking into all the useful dates, finds the `index.html`, and then just skips to the next directory, without downloading the relevant hdf file:

```
--2013-06-14 13:09:18--  http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD09GA.005/2004.01.01/
Reusing existing connection to e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD09GA.005/2004.01.01/index.html'

[    <=>                                                                                                                                  ] 174,182      134K/s   in 1.3s    

2013-06-14 13:09:20 (134 KB/s) -  `e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD09GA.005/2004.01.01/index.html' saved [174182]

Removing e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD09GA.005/2004.01.01/index.html since it should be rejected.

--2013-06-14 13:09:20--  http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD09GA.005/2004.01.02/
[...]
```

If I ignore the `-A` option, only the `index.html` file is downloaded to my system, but it appears it's not parsed and the links are not followed. I don't really know what more is required to make this work, as I can't see why it doesn't!!!

### SOLUTION

In the end, the problem was due to an old bug in the local version of wget. However, I ended up writing my own script for downloading MODIS data from the server above. The script is pure Python, and is available from [here](https://github.com/jgomezdans/get_modis).

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use pyModis instead of wget which is a Free and Open Source Python based library to work with MODIS data. It offers bulk-download for user selected time ranges, mosaicking of MODIS tiles, and the reprojection from Sinusoidal to other projections, convert HDF format to other formats. See

http://www.pymodis.org/

Comment: I had already written my own tool for this ;-D See http://github.com/jgomezdans/get_modis